# Forcing an entire website to always use https AND www without breaking external images?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying to force a ***private*** WordPress website running Simple Press Forum software as well as plenty of custom non-WordPress pages to always use `www.` and `https` but subdomains should not be forced to https

When I do it via .htaccess with the use of Rewrite rules it doesn't work correctly.

- Some rewrite rules try to force subdomains (we don't want that)
- Some rewrite rules do not always correctly force www. or https
- **For some reason all external images stop working even though they're not being told to be rewrote...**

Also how can I have an iframe added without disabling ssl for that page?

Answer (score 0):

While you state that it's a custom site, i assume you have access to webserver configuration files.

To enforce ssl (https), use the following statement in your /etc/apache2/sites-available/default (or equivalent config file):

```
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
```

so the Directory section looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Redirect permanent / https://hdcs.cz/
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

After making the changes, restart apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

External images, fetched via non-ssl http will work fine, but the browser will consider such page as partially encrypted. The behavior you are getting with external images may be caused by the browser, please check that.

As far as i'm concerned, you should be able to embed content into an iframe, on a ssl-enabled site, only if the content itself is being fetched via https.

Regards,

Tomas

Comment: Hi, I do not have access to them it's hosted on a managed hosting plan. I have cPanel access but as far as I can see I can't do what you're suggesting which is why I have to use the rewrite route.